# sFlutter Unhandled Exception : InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter

**I am trying to set the response in the _dataFromAPI but it show exception : InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<dynamic**

```
class _CryptoCurrencyScreenState extends State<CryptoCurrencyScreen> {
    
      var _dataFromAPI;
      var list;
      var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
    
      Future<List<Data>> getCurrencies() async {
        var url =
            Uri.parse("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/map");
        final response = await http.get(url);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            List _dataFromAPI = json.decode(response.body);
            return _dataFromAPI.map((data) => new Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
          }
        }
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        refreshListData();
      }
    
      Future<Null> refreshListData() async {
        refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
        setState(() {
          list = getCurrencies();
        });
        return null;
      }
    }
```

**How could I fix it?**

Comment: Can you provide your response output?

Comment: [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/9740/QSomzo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `List` with `List<String, dynamic>`, like this: `List<String, dynamic> _dataFromAPI = json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: It show error : [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5376/YWx6xQ.png)